# Monotouch: How to get a localized string from sqlite DB

Tags: sqlite, localization, xamarin.ios

I want to display a list of items from my sqlite DB in a tableView. These items need to be localized depending on the language selected on the phone.

As an example, if on of the items in the DB was "Hello", it should be displayed as "Hello" in english, "Hallo" in german and so on.

I already tried to store the complete (NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("Hello", "Hello")) and just storing the identifier for each string, but neither worked.

Any idea where I made a mistake?

Thanks in advance, BanZai

Comment: Hard to say where you made a mistake without any code. If you want to localize your project, make subfolders called "de", "en" etc. If you use NSBUndle.MainBundle.GetLocalizedString(), iOS will get the string from the locale file in the subfolder that is corresponding to the OS's language setting. But I don't really understand what the Sqlite DB should be for then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, made a very stupid mistake. I filled the DB with already localized strings, so obviously the language matched with the original language, but after changing it, the content in the DB stayed the same, thx @Krumelur for trying to help